# MYSQL #1136 - Column count doesn't match value count at row 1 though they are equal

Tags: php, mysql

I keep getting the following error though no. of columns and no. of values match, so I wonder can someone help ?

```
INSERT INTO `user_dates` (`id`, `date`, `user_id`) VALUES(26545, '2016-04-28', 35);
```

My Table structure is:

```
CREATE TABLE `user_dates` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `user_dates_user_id_foreign` (`user_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `user_dates_user_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=10459 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: Your `id` is auto-increment. Do not provide a value!

Comment: I tried not providing a value but it didn't work...can it be a constraint issue? @juergend

Comment: You tried `INSERT INTO user_dates (date, user_id) VALUES('2016-04-28', 35);`?

Comment: Yes and I have Foreign keys in another table (users) which are referenced from user_dates @juergend and it failed. same error

Comment: I'm disabling all of the constrains i have on this table and i'm changing the auto increment to UNIQUE  and  PK only

Comment: I would not recommend changing it. Do you have a trigger on one of the tables that might fail with that error?

Comment: Yes @juergend, thanks that was a great help.... i didn;t expect it to be a trigger thing because the trigger was inserting the values from this table to another table user_dates2 to keep track of the records change...Thanks, thumbs up for u